# Keep one maximum value per row in a matrix in R

Tags: r, k-means

I have a matrix like this:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    1    0
[2,]    1    1    0
[3,]    0    0    1
```

The ones in each row represent the maximum values per row for e.g. i had the matrix

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   11   32   12
[2,]   16   16   14
[3,]   19   18   27
```

Now in this matrix in the second row I had two same maximum values (16) which got replaced by two 1's in the second row in the previous matrix, now I want to remove duplicate maximum values in my rows of a matrix so in essence what I need is something like this:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    1    0
[2,]    1    0    0
[3,]    0    0    1
```

i.e keep one maximum value per row at random (ties should be broken at random and only one maximum value kept) and make all the entries other than that zero. Please can any one provide me a code snippet to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or you could use. This would be faster.

```
  ret[cbind(seq_len(nrow(mat2)),max.col(mat2, "first"))] <- 1
  ret
  #     [,1] [,2] [,3]
  #[1,]    0    1    0
  #[2,]    1    0    0
  #[3,]    0    0    1
```

#### data

```
 mat1 <- matrix(c(0,1,0, 1,1,0,0,0,1), ncol=3)
 mat2 <- matrix(c(11,16,19, 32, 16, 18, 12, 14, 27), ncol=3)
 ret <- matrix(0, ncol(mat1), nrow(mat1))
```

Comment: +1!! How long has this function existed?! It has totally slipped under my radar. You can specify `"first"` `"random"` or `"last"` as differng `ties.method` ' s too.

Comment: @thelatemail Recently somebody used this function and I was not also aware of the options until today.

Comment: +1 also.  Why is it called `max.col`?  Strange name when the help says *Find the maximum position for each row of a matrix, breaking ties at random.*  Should be `max.row`.

Comment: @RichardScriven - it's the **max**imum **col**umn in each row, so that makes sense to me.

Comment: I guess, if you want to be all "logical" about it.

Answer (score 2):

if `mat` is your original matrix,

#### Create an empty matrix full of zeros, of the correct size and dim

```
ret <- matrix(rep(0, length(mat)), ncol=ncol(mat))
```

#### assign the required values to 1.  Note that `which.max` breaks tie by choosing the first occurrence.

```
ret[ cbind(seq(nrow(mat)), apply(mat, 1, which.max))  ] <- 1

ret
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    1    0
[2,]    1    0    0
[3,]    0    0    1
```

---

Alternatively, if you truly want to split ties at random, you would use something like this as the index to `ret`:

```
cbind(seq(nrow(mat)), apply(mat, 1, function(x) 
     sample(which(x == max(x)), 1)
))
```

Comment: Alternative: `ret[cbind(seq_len(nrow(mat)),tapply(mat,row(mat),which.max))] <- 1`

Comment: @thelatemail, not sure abot the use of `tapply` over `apply`.  `tapply` just wraps `by` and is much slower

Comment: @RicardoSaporta - ignore my musings - `apply` seems about as fast as you can get.

Comment: @thelatemail, no sweat ;)